# Is this a bug in the rep notfication or rep history system?

Tags: support, reputation

This morning my rep was 315. I downvoted an answer (and left a comment explaining why I thought it was a bad answer) which took me to 314.

When I next visited the site, I got a green +1 icon telling me my rep had increased. Clicking on my rep history, it says my last increase was +2 for an edit a few days ago. I was on 314 and I've got +2, that should be 316... but I was on 315.

What's happened is that the answer that I down voted has been deleted so I've got my 1 back, but the 1 point deduction/reimbursement for downvoting does not appear anywhere in the rep history.

It took me a while to figure this out.

Is this a bug? Or am I fundamentally misunderstanding how it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the right behaviour. It's not shown in the quick list of achievements, but you can see it if you go to your profile page and look at the reputation tab. For example:

[image]